# What could be the potential cause of "AMQ222196: Could not find binding with..." warnings on ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have a clustered setup for ActiveMQ Artemis servers in AWS. Over the past week we have seen tons of the below warning messages in the logs. The CPU and the memory of the server is crossing the threshold forcing us to restart the service and even the instance quite a few times. There isn't much on the internet about the cause, but some indication that this is perhaps due to message binding impacted by clustering. Even so, We aren't sure what in the message is causing this issue as the payload's aren't much different than what we have been getting. There were only a handful of these warning messages in our logs over a period of several week, but since a week the number has grown by the millions. What could be going wrong, Any insights appreciated.

Here is a sample warning message.

```
2020-02-13 14:28:58,645 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222196: Could not find binding with id=11,114,895,059 on routeFromCluster for message=AMQPMessage [durable=true, messageID=13052078659, address=XXX.XXXX.XXX, size=1982, applicationProperties=ApplicationProperties{{Lynx04=XXX, LFW03=Workflow, Lynx06=0, LFW00=wsaz.com, LFW01=EN, LFW02=Group1, Lynx0800=Thu Feb 13 14:25:16 UTC 2020, Lynx14=Artemis}}, properties=Properties{messageId=null, userId=null, to='XXX.XXXX.XXX', subject='null', replyTo='null', correlationId=null, contentType=null, contentEncoding=null, absoluteExpiryTime=null, creationTime=Thu Feb 13 14:25:16 UTC 2020, groupId='null', groupSequence=null, replyToGroupId='null'}, extraProperties = TypedProperties[_AMQ_ROUTE_TO$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-prod-cluster.649d96bf-de2b-11e9-8889-02460ffd6a18=[0000 0002 9531 B172 0000 0002 9818 16D3 0000 0002 9781 23E6 0000 0002 9561  ...  0002 9637 EACC 0000 0002 968A 3628 0000 0002 9856 9B99 0000 0002 94EF 2768),bytesAsLongs(11092996466,11141650131,11131757542,11096127999,11149827997,11117409910,11149918653,11138359325,11112736022,11149918632,11108974130,11144407714,11123284712,11148617189,11146419442,11122154478,11148039779,11064627367,11131350943,11114442863,11139909372,11144226395,11095685669,11103132284,11099419329,11084788097,11148135466,11143940580,11149918638,11109381222,11126002110,11126950313,11148428980,11117155793,11140480199,11139277653,11119611516,11098239884,11145802207,11014049428,11134205560,11146217595,11114954290,11084786535,11135336274,11123665250,11105586606,11129313833,11132962444,11146089773,11137314753,11126366539,11109994516,11073083162,11087684856,11147132243,11145040591,11094010279,11114674799,11132425629,11088767935,11149538977,11104658758,11148460742,11149950613,11138829338,11144364588,11149476058,11084787961,11113906745,11146285410,11093765110,11138612090,11139731785,11110408375,11143186417,11113136442,11119610672,11109786298,11122083740,11110278591,11141726527,11114895059,11117937113,11123403149,11090488836,11139696851,11122094684,11115901261,11142841379,11130377839,11084795806,11147462487,11145229318,11104429162,11122593413,11112278054,11089644700,11070671179,11124057217,11132105030,11101814107,11084782331,11140614142,11149574783,11140009327,11147712022,11147183888,11145259532,11125454839,11114038008,11089380671,11144707655,11139158341,11114021315,11096340984,11132553630,11149600829,11146856401,10971057311,11148283108,11103778705,11129000641,11143975596,11131382377,11120934818,11093385121,11107606278,11148305557,11118746404,11091098877,11085491332,11097089647,10988992712,11137452973,11115917580,11127899290,11101015653,11114183658,11135837318,11113758214,11142658071,11098077053,11146184168,11114457661,11106253975,11140526932,11099405130,10971056680,11105307909,11148998918,11136363994,11125654918,11102307257,11091291307,11142108165,11114313632,11093942167,11139930712,11124486034,11084782195,11126294694,11102939779,11119123452,11114885577,11053232850,11105330122,11142317710,11116463260,11125479830,11104888674,11112385007,11144512861,11133730940,11146759287,11149918946,11134800699,11142815087,11147907036,11102239459,11084788970,11149919242,11096183632,11106182883,11124048304,11097860553,11097867911,11127858305,11098031010,11090856621,11110221715,11146133984,11090279873,11111346032,11147122670,11119741780,11116649100,11145948039,11113685176,11145848212,11095636831,11027240050,11128886635,11115467327,11132322872,11119093668,11148453343,11095717270,11144281537,11138181284,11112832143,11132076670,11084786647,11144714265,11085070331,11095789149,11071261927,11136919084,11119790568,11113875378,11092501818,11144373199,11148346674,11096341453,11144748254,11140270020,11121426358,11115244083,11101186600,11092088069,11105883575,11084785822,11104044765,11139226916,11133544544,11146097356,11144211794,11065330017,11147957704,11133008935,11131266166,11094121668,11103614159,11136487583,11079726569,11109219673,11090326301,11130195903,11128559152,11148101040,11144391255,11149425102,11107019925,11123927112,11118552410,11119937508,11129354209,11147285595,11098484923,11124498510,11147975157,11125631041,11104477995,11110181580,11115574824,11145747353,11088635752],_AMQ_ROUTE_TO$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-prod-cluster.5299b255-de38-11e9-98e3-12ec481c37ce=[0000 0001 8276 8FE3 0000 0001 8253 F69A 0000 0001 8280 BFF1 0000 0001 8275 EA99),bytesAsLongs(6483775459,6481507994,6484443121,6483733145],_AMQ_ROUTE_TO$.artemis.internal.sf.artemis-prod-cluster.627413b2-de38-11e9-9de6-0abf301c95f0=[0000 0001 8269 DCE4 0000 0001 8254 160F 0000 0001 825A 2080),bytesAsLongs(6482943204,6481516047,6481911936],_AMQ_AD=XXX.XXXX.XXX]] binding = BindingsImpl [name=XXX.XXXX.XXX]
```

Here is the address settings in my broker.xml. As you can see I'm not explicitly configuring any address settings for the addresses that are created by the publisher and subscriber applications.

```xml
<address-settings>
    <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
    <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
    </address-setting>
    <!--default for catch all-->
    <address-setting match="#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
    </address-setting>
</address-settings>

<addresses>
    <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
        <queue name="DLQ" />
        </anycast>
    </address>
    <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
        <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
        </anycast>
    </address>
    <address name="RWN.Q">
        <anycast>
        <queue  name="RWN.Q"/>
        </anycast>
    </address>
    <address name="BNA.T">
        <multicast>
        <queue name="BNA.T"/>
        </multicast>
    </address>
    <address name="BNS.T">
        <multicast>
        <queue name="BNS.T"/>
        </multicast>
    </address>
    <address name="BNT.T">
        <multicast>
        <queue name="BNT.T"/>
        </multicast>
    </address>
</addresses>
```

Comment: What's your topology? Are you using auto-created addresses & queues? If so, is auto-delete enabled?

Comment: My cluster topology is symmetric and I have a predefined addresses and queues but I presume that I'm not preventing any addresses and queues from being auto created (Because that are a few applications which publish and subscribe to Artemis an their queues aren't predefined in my config).

Comment: Is the address noted in the WARN message (which you have redacted) predefined? Also, is there a specific reason you're clustering instead of using a single instance?

Comment: No it is not a predefined address. Interestingly, I've also found that of all the addresses that are associated with this warning message, one address is predefined but not used by any publisher. That one address is used for address forwarding using diverts and is used by subscribers.

The reason I'm using clustering is for load balancing and performance. Our publishers and subscribers are global and hence the need.

Comment: Is auto-delete enabled? If so, you may want to disable it. Race conditions with message load-balancing and auto-deletion can lead to situations like this. Also, I'm curious if you conducted performance tests to determine that you need to cluster. A single broker can potentially handle millions of messages per second, and clustering can actually reduce overall throughput in certain use-cases due to the migration of messages between nodes. It's important that you have solid performance data to support clustering if you want to maximize throughput.

Comment: I added the address settings from my broker.xml file. Addresses section has explicitly added addresses but as I mentioned there are Client which write to addresses that can be created on the fly. Since those addresses are not defined, Wouldn't their creation and deletion managed by artemis? How do you suggest configuring the auto-delete on addresses not defined in the config?

Comment: Try adding `<auto-delete-queues>true</auto-delete-queues>` and `<auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>` to the `<address-setting match="#">`. Also, can you elaborate on your performance testing and the results that pushed you towards clustering? I'm coming back to this because eliminating the cluster would be one way to resolve this problem.

Comment: OK, Will give that a shot and update here. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Sorry, I meant `<auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>` and `<auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>` to disable auto-deletion.