# Could not find bindings [...] ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0

Tags: activemq-artemis

We have a couple of problems with Artemis ActiveMQ 2.17.0.
We have a clustered setup On-Prem and our topology is a symmetric cluster with 3 brokers (masters) for high availability and fault tolerance.

Here is an example of `ha-policy` and `cluster-connections`:

```xml
<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <address></address> <!-- Empty address means load balancing messages -->
      <connector-ref>artemis</connector-ref>
      <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

```xml
<ha-policy>
   <replication>
      <master>
         <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
      </master>
   </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

Which are replicated on every node of our topology.
We have a couple of millions of messages per day and a thousands of addresses and queues.
We have persistence enabled with `<persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>`.

We already saw [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60215644/what-could-be-the-potential-cause-of-amq222196-could-not-find-binding-with) but, unfortunately, didn't help us.

Here's a simple warning message:

```
2023-04-04 09:44:09,188 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222196: Could not find binding with id=22,532,404,009 on routeFromCluster for message=CoreMessage[messageID=22536382880,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, timestamp=0,expiration=Tue Apr 04 09:54:09 CEST 2023, durable=true, address=<address>,size=950,properties=TypedProperties[mqtt.message.retain=false,mqtt.qos.level=1]]@1453606969 binding = BindingsImpl [name=<address>]
```

The problem is that there are a millions of messages like these in our logs, which grows very fast.

Here's an example of address setting in our `broker.xml`:

```xml
<address-setting match="status.#">
   <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
   <expiry-address>ExpiryQueueStatus</expiry-address>
   <auto-create-expiry-resources>true</auto-create-expiry-resources>
   <expiry-queue-prefix>EXP.</expiry-queue-prefix>
   <min-expiry-delay>10</min-expiry-delay>
   <max-expiry-delay>600000</max-expiry-delay>
   <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
   <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
   <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
   <max-size-bytes>100Mb</max-size-bytes>
   <page-size-bytes>10Mb</page-size-bytes>
   <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
   <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
   <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
   <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
   <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
   <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
   <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
   <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
   <auto-delete-created-queues>false</auto-delete-created-queues>
</address-setting>
```

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 is quite old. Have you tried ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a cluster?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram the reason why we're using a cluster is only for load balancing and mostly for high availability in case one of the three machines goes down. I know that a single Artemis machines can handle a millions of message per second.

Comment: Hi @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino do you know if there are some problem to upgrade from version 2.17.0 to 2.28.0? In particular for Java version (from 2.20.0 Java 11 is required).

Answer (score 0):

A "binding" is basically the generic name for anything that is bound to an address. This could be a "local" queue (i.e. a queue that physically exists on the broker), a "remote" queue (i.e. a queue that physically exists on another broker, e.g. in the cluster), a divert, etc.

When you see this kind of message it means that a message was being sent from one broker in the cluster to another broker in the cluster, but by the time the message actually arrived the queue were it was supposed to be routed is no longer there.

In this case, it's an MQTT message that looks to be going to a subscriber that closed their subscription while the message was in flight.

This isn't terribly uncommon when you have lots of pub/sub clients coming and going all the time.